# Forcing HTTPS with Symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to force all requests to example.com/checkout/ to use HTTPS.  I read the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html) and have this in my security.yml file:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/checkout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

However, when I go to http://example.com/checkout/, I am NOT redirected to HTTPS.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is to allow user if he is using `https` channel. To redirect on https, you should use htaccess or, just check inside controller action.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding this page? It says that would force https. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html

Comment: correct, it will force user to use https to match route, otherwise 404 not found. :)

Comment: So do you get a `404` or do you still get the page without SSL? You've cleared your caches after making the change, right?

Comment: I do not get a 404, I get the page without SSL.  Yes, I cleared the cache.  The only thing I can think of is that the entire server is behind a password in the Apache config, but that never affected any other security rules.

Comment: And FYI, adding it to the route works: `@Route("/checkout/", schemes = "https")`

Comment: Do you have another `access_control` setting that could be matched by `/checkout`? Perhaps a rule that includes `(.*)`?

Comment: There are all the rules: `access_control:- { path: ^/checkout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https } - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_BACKEND_USER, host: backend.example.com }
- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_BACKEND_USER, host: dev.backend.example.com }`

Comment: You didn't happen to figure this out, did you?

Comment: @JTG yes I did, see the answer I just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did not have a firewall setup.  I needed to add this under the firewalls section of security.yml:

```
checkout:
    pattern: ^/checkout
    anonymous: ~
```

And this worked:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/checkout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yaml:

```
 secure:
    path:     /secure
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:secure }
    schemes:  [https]
```

Or Annotation:

```
/**
 * @Route("/secure", schemes = "https")
 */
class SecureController
{
     ...
}
```

For more details: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html

Comment: Because I will have many different controllers in the secure area, I wanted to setup the rules in security.yml instead of on each individual route.  This is how the symfony docs recommends to do it if you want to secure a whole area: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html

Answer (score -2):

This is to allow user if he is using https channel. To redirect on https, you should use htaccess or, just check inside controller action.

Symfony configs will force user to use https to match route, otherwise 404 not found. :)

Comment: Sorry - not true. Just tested it in my `security.yml` and go a forced HTTPS instead of a 404. You should also not touch the `.htaccess` in a Symfony project.

Comment: This document explains it should redirect: https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/security/access_control.html#access-enforcement